# encode accented characters into html entities using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-entities, html-encode

I would like to convert this text `éàè` to `&eacute;&agrave;&egrave;` using javascript.

I tried `$('<textarea />').text("éàe").html();` but it doesn't encode the accented characters...

The `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml` works correctly in Java, is there an equivalent for javascript ?

Comment: Do you know *HOW* Apache does it in Java? It builds a giant cheat sheet: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/Entities.java#Entities.0HTML40_ARRAY

Comment: yeah I just saw the library [he.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) does the same thing, I wanted to not use an external library

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the ultimate goal? Entities for common Latin characters were barely necessary in the late 1990s and 20 decades have passed.

Comment: Also, do you strictly need named entities? Are numeric entities an option?

Comment: we have some problem of characters encoding when submitting a form field to the server, for some users the special characters `éàè...` are not correctly decoded by the server, I can't reproduce the problem on my desk with ff and chrome (it works correctly), I suspect a problem of client side encoding. The quick fix is to send html entities to the server

Comment: It feels like you aren't using UTF-8 explicitly but relying on defaults...

Comment: I thought the same thing, but threre is a `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>` at the begin of the jsp

Comment: That's a manifesto to declare you are using UTF-8. You still need to actually use it ;-)

Comment: how can I specify to use it ?

Comment: Well... I can refer you to [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through#279279). It's a PHP question but it contains valuable information anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ES6, you might be interested in **tagged template literals**...

```js
function htmlentities(raw) {
  const str = raw[0];

  return str.replace(/é/g, '&eacute;')
            .replace(/à/g, '&agrave;')
            .replace(/è/g, '&egrave;');
}

console.log(htmlentities`éàè`);
```

Comment: I want to convert all the accented charaters, I realized there is no native function to do this, I will use the [he.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) library